# Compare Worksheet Values (Text and Arithmetic)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with 2 worksheets, each of them composed of 60 rows and 7 columns (first column consists of text, the rest only numbers).

I found VBA code in order to compare the values of the 2 sheets. If there is a difference, the cell is filled red, but there is an issue with the columns containing numbers:

`Cell in 1st Sheet Value: 6102.75`

`Cell in 1st Sheet Value: 6102.75000001`

--> The cell is highlighted red.

Which changes should I make in the code in order not to highlight the cell, if the numbers are equal up to 4 demical points? I think that I have to make a change in the code, to compare separately for text and numbers.

```
Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String, shtAfter As String)
Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange

If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed

mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

Next

'Display a message box stating the number of differences found

MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtAfter).Select

End Sub
```

Looking forward to your comments

Comment: Use the `Round` function but read this first https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-vba-round-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IsNumeric to determine if the two values are numbers then Round to truncate decimals to 4 places.

```
Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String, shtAfter As String)

    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim mydiffs As Integer

    For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange
        if isnumeric(mycell.Value) and isnumeric(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value) then

            If round(mycell.Value, 4) <> round(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value, 4) Then

                mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

            end if

        elseif mycell.Value <> ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value then

            mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

        end if

    Next mycell 

    'Display a message box stating the number of differences found

    MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtAfter).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Format` function define the number of decimal places you want to compare and use the `IsNumeric` function to check wether a value is a number or not.

Example Code:

```
Cell A1: 6102.75    
Cell A2: 6102.75000001

Sub test
  'Since in your example both worksheets share the same layout, you only need to check
  'if one of the values is numeric, since the other value will automaticly be the same
  If IsNumeric(Cells(1,1).Value) Then
    MsgBox (Format(Cells(1,1).Value, "0.0000") = Format(Cells(1,1).Value, "0.0000"))
  Else
    MsgBox Cells(1,1).Value = Cells(1,2).Value
  End If      
End Sub
```

> The first parameter of Format is the value you want to format
>
> The second parameter of Format is the string which defines the format
>
> the the 4 zeros after the dot define the number of decimals

**EDIT:**
Since @jeeped postet a solution using the `Round` Function.

Note that using the `Format` Function cuts the rest of the decimal places, instead of rounding.

So `6102,75` and `6102,75005` would be still equal.

**EDIT2:**

@jeeped improved the Format-String, so there is not even the need to check if a value is a number or a text.

Updated Example Code:

```
Cell A1: 6102.75    
Cell A2: 6102.75000001

Sub test
  MsgBox Format(Cells(1, 1).Value, "0.0000;@") = Format(Cells(1, 2).Value, "0.0000;@")
End Sub
```

Using this Format-String, the function will return the number cut to 4 decimal digits if its a number, or it returns the enire text if it's a text.

Comment: I imagine that range.text (the number as displayed in the cell) should work as well for comparison so long as the two worksheets share a common formatting layout.

Comment: If you used `Format(Cells(1,1).Value, "0.0000;@")` you could discard IsNumeric.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the additional information! Im not familiar with the syntax of the Format-String you used, can you explain how this works?

Comment: If Cells(1,1).Value is a number, format it with 4 decimal places, if it is text result is the text. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-apply-a-custom-number-format-6c308025-35da-4047-9481-c146a12063df

Comment: The worksheets have a common formatting layout so it is working!

Comment: If Format(mycell.Value, "0.0000;@") <> Format(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value, "0.0000;@") Then

                          mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                          mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
    End If